# JQuery not executing in Cordova

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, cordova

I'm working on a mobile app using Cordova.
There is a page where I want to have a JQuery slider.
To achieve this I'm using the popular swipe.js, which I'm calling like so:
`<script src="js/swipe.js"></script>`

However when I emulate the app and go to the page it just shows me the static HTML.
Even weirder, when I put the WWW in MAMP and run it in the browser it also shows me static HTML untill I refresh the page once, after which it runs as I want it to.

I'm using deviceready but it doesn't seem to help much:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function(){
    Slider = $('#slider').Swipe({
        auto: 1000,
        continuous: true
    }).data('Swipe');

    $('#share-button').click(function() {
        $('#social').css('display', 'block');
        $('#overlay').css('display', 'block');
    });

    $('#overlay').click(function() {
        $('#social').css('display', 'none');
        $('#overlay').css('display', 'none');
    });
},true);
```

I set the timer to 1000ms so I can see if the jquery is working or not.

Comment: Maybe the device is ready but not the document? Try wrapping your slider code with jquery's document ready maybe?

Comment: @AntoineCloutier I've tried that and it doesn't work :S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of document.addEventListener use jQuery pageshow event to initialize Swipe Slider.
http://www.w3schools.com/jquerymobile/event_pageshow.asp

Answer (score 0):

1.Always use deviceready with cordova you.

2.Make sure you have all the javascript need cordova,cordova_plugins,jquery,swipe ect.

3.Make sure it actually deviceready is firing.

This is how i do it

```
 $(document).ready( function() {
       document.addEventListener("deviceready", controller.StartApp, false);
   });
controller.StartApp = function()
{
alert("Device ready");
}
```

Comment: what is `controller.StartApp`?

Comment: Its function that starts the app doesn't matter. By start i mean check for network check for device type iOS,android ect.

Comment: So how would I execute my own code then? After the `false);`?

Comment: I update the answer so you can see whats is startapp.

Comment: I've tried your method but it shows the same result as mine (static html). The other jquery code is not working either, so I think that my swipe.js is not being loaded properly and it causes the other jquery code to break.

Comment: this may be stupid question but is all your html + js hosted in your cordova project and on what you are testing iOS, adroid, ect?