# Swipe JS not swiping

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, cordova

This question is related to one I closed shortly before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24262829/jquery-not-executing-in-cordova).

I got the slidershow from swipe JS working, but the swiping doesn't seem to work at all.
The way I'm loading in the slider is as such:

```
$(document).on("pageshow", function(){
    Slider = $('.slider').Swipe({
        auto: 3000,
        continuous: true,
        disableScroll: true
    }).data('Swipe');
});
```

I'm emulating the app on my own iPhone and the iPhone simulator from XCode but neither seems to pick up the swipe I'm trying to make (left, right, down, up).

Am I missing something that I need for Cordova?

**EDIT**
I have managed to get the first slider to swipe using this:

```
$(document).on("pageshow", function(){
    Slider = $('.slider').Swipe({
        auto: 4000,
        continuous: true,
        disableScroll: true
    }).data('Swipe');
});

$('.slider').on('swiperight', swiperightHandler);
$('.slider').on('swipeleft', swipeleftHandler);

function swiperightHandler() {
    Slider.prev();
}

function swipeleftHandler() {
    Slider.next();
}
```

The problem is that this only lets me swipe on the first slider.
I have multiple sliders (they all are exactly the same, and I'm ussing classes as selectors). I think the problem is with my `on.("pageshow",` because it sets the `Slider` variable once and doesn't reset it.

The automatic sliding of the slider does work for some reason.

Does anybody know how to make the swiping work for all sliders?

Comment: try thia plugin http://www.netcu.de/jquery-touchwipe-iphone-ipad-library or this one https://github.com/marcandre/detect_swipe

Comment: @RachelGallen But swipeJS should already be doing this for me shouldn't it?

Comment: detect swipe is a more modern version and has fixes for swipejs in it

Comment: you should add document.addEventListener("deviceready", function(){ ),true around your code

Comment: I found out that JQuery Mobile has a swipe detector built in :^).

Comment: you should still add deviceready line around your code

Comment: You didn't added document.addEventListener("deviceready", function(){  // Your Code...  });

Comment: I added it and now my code doesn't work :/

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem by removing the swipe handlers.
It turns out that the slider already had a built-in swipe and there was no need for more.